# How does the app 2GIS work?

Tags: gis

I want to understand completely how does the app 2GIS work?

App: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.dublgis.dgismobile

Please elaborate as much as possible.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks how an app works.

Answer (score 0):

I have some inside.

They have there own cartographer that draws maps, and call center that actualize DB.

All data stores locally and updates once a month. (They may change data update cycle, of course)

DB thay store in there own format, using Qt. All core functions are also on Qt, but UI is native.

Comment: Ok. Isn't it possible to get those maps from Google maps? Why draw it again? Can't we use the offline map capability of Google maps? It will show the business listings too.

Comment: @anmolagrawal this app was made for Russia first of all. And google maps here is very bad.

Comment: @anmolagrawal 2gis has there own actual map and catalog, they manually keep it actual. Google has no actual data fore many places.